# Trying to scrape item from website

Tags: vb.net-2010

I was attempting to create a simple program that would pull a text item from a website and add it to the textbox. I'm simply just experimenting and thought I could do it but it is not that easy for me. I know how to get the entire source code of a website(below). It has a id I know but it does not have a tag name. So Im not really sure how to make it read through the text and only keep the part next to the id . Or would it be better to use a Webbrowser tool and then try and get the text item like that. I'm just trying to do whatever is faster. I think my 1st option is better because it would be better for the computer's ram. Using the code below I don't know what to add next?

```
Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("Website")
Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
Dim source As String = sr.ReadToEnd()
```

Lets say the id is "name" for example. Viewing the source of the page this is what the part looks like(below). How can I parse through the source which is a string and find this section, get the name Brandon, and add it to the textbox.

```
<span id="name">Brandon</span>
```

Comment: You can use HTML Agility Pack to parse the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to go about this. I'm not going to write any source code though since I haven't used Visual Basic in a very long time. But if you Google for how to do any of the following you should find many tutorials and documents on it.

**Regular Expressions**

Using a Regular Expression on the full source code can help you find the element by searching for the ID attribute which should be unique. Regular Expressions can sometimes be very slow, which is why if you have to perform a lot of searches on large sections of text, it should be avoided.

`/<([a-z0-9]+)\sid="name"(.*?)>(.*?)<\//` -> Not Tested, but might help you

**String Position**

Using a function that will find the position of a substring in a string would be useful. In C it's `strstr` and in PHP it's `strpos`. These type of functions will give you starting position of a string, in which your case would be searching for `id="name"`. Once you find that, you will find the position of the end of the tag and then find the closing tag for that element. You then will perform a substring function that will get you the text starting at position X for the length of that you specify, which would be the `closing tag position - end of opening tag position`.

**HTML / XML Library**

There are probably a ton of HTML / XML libraries that will parse the document into some sort of object or an array. You then can loop through these elements until you find the one you are looking for. Some of these libraries may even have search functions of element ID's similar to how JavaScript will sort for a specific element.

These libraries may be hard to get started with, but they will offer you a lot of options in the future if you need to continue finding more HTML elements.